# Wordpress token validation using Wordpress' oauth2 validation API is returning 400

Tags: wordpress, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm integrating WordPress REST APIs with a spring Boot application.

When I extract the Authorisation token and I try to validate the token on Postman, I get a response object signifying it is valid. This is the URL for validating the Wordpress token which I am calling on Postman and is returning a 200 and a response object

*https://public-api.wordpresas.com/oauth2/token-info?client_id=100000&token=830jgfnwhatevertoken*

Now with my integration in the app, this same URL is returning a 400

```
`{

"error": "invalid_request",

"error_description": "The specified token is invalid."
}`
```

Please I will like to know what could be wrong. Thank you

Comment: If you are expecting a JWT token, then it typically should start with the letters ey....., in your case the token starts with 830xxxxxx, then it is not a JWT token... but all depends on what your API expects.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. The token, when retrieved from the Wordpress.com OAuth provider, includes special characters. So you need to encode the token before passing it to the `token-info` endpoint.

Looks like you should be able to do [something like this in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-url-encoding-decoding#encode-the-url):

```java
URLEncoder.encode("830jgfnwhatevertoken", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```